# Can I use SQL in Script editor inSharepoint ( webpart)?

Tags: sql, sharepoint

I am working on Sharepoint site that already exists and I need to create a new webpart dedicated for a certain form to complete, then I should use the answers collected from the form to produce a "result page". When I open the "Edit source" Or "Embeded code", I can easily use html or javascript to display whatever I want, my question is: In that script editor(snippet) can I use Sql as well?
As I said, I'm going to need some sql queries to extract the answers from the form.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is not possible.

If what you are doing is something like storing a form submission in a list and then displaying the result in a different page:

1. Create a form - using normal HTML/JS etc.
2. On submit button click - store the information in the list
3. Retrieve the information from the list using the ID(or any other criteria) on the results page and display it (again using HTML/JS)

Have a look at this JS library, which has SQL like syntax, for working within SharePoint:
https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful :)